# Efficient way to compare string in lexical analyzer

Tags: c++, lexical-analysis

Basically this will only parse the string literals and will output the type of token it has.
I used the Aho-Cohasick algorithm to make sure that the string is valid or existing in the symbol lists.
My question is should I used the "==" operator of string, the drawback is I'm going to used the if-else statement, or I'm should I use the crc16 calculation and later be used in switch case statement for better readability or performance wise, which of the two is better?

```
Token Lexer::type_identifier()
{
    char* name = type_name();
    string sym_name(name);
    trie.only_whole_words();
    auto result = trie.parse_text(sym_name);   //trie using Aho-Corasick algorithm

    if (!result.size())
        throw - 1;
    
    unsigned short crc = crc16(name, strlen(name));

    switch (crc) {
    case 0xfb81:
        return Token(Identifiers::e_T, "T");
    case 0x9b7a:
        return Token(Identifiers::e_OpAdd, "<Addition>");
    }

    //if(symname == "T")
    //  return Token(Identifiers::e_T, "T");
    return Token();
}
```

Comment: Could you encode the information in the trie directly?

Comment: What I did is I calculated all the hashes first in the constructor then stored these hashes in struct.